# Install Oracle's JRE on Netgear Solaris missing libCrun.so

Tags: java, oracle

We're trying to install Oracle's java runtime on one of Netgear's ReadyDATA NAS-type systems with x86 architecture that runs on Solaris. When starting the java vm, it reports:

> Error: dl failure on line 863
>
> Error: failed /.system/usr/java/jre1.7.0_45/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so,
>   because ld.so.1: java: fatal: libCrun.so.1: open failed: No such file
>   or directory

indicating some missing library.

Does anyone know where to get the libCrun shared object?

Comment: What version of Solaris?  Have you tried searching for an answer, this was a known issue and there are patches.

Comment: It's Solaris 11, or actually NexentaOS_134f on a Netgear DataReady NAS type of system.

Comment: Sure, I've been looking around. The closest I get is http://timezra.blogspot.nl/2007/10/installing-jdk-6-in-nexenta-zone.html, which seems to have touched this problem, but doesn't provide a solution. Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Found it on http://ftp.nexentastor.org/dists/hardy-unstable.

Comment: Great - add that as an answer yourself in case others search for the same problem, and accept it - you'll get the reputation score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it on http://ftp.nexentastor.org/dists/hardy-unstable.

The non-free zone contains the package sun-java6-jre. Installling that one may also install dependencies that are not compatible with the device. So don't do that.

Best is to install sunwlibc from this repository (also in the non-free zone) and next download the appropriate jre from Oracle's web site and install that.